# Evaluate how much space will be freed by VACUUM in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to AWS doc:

> Amazon Redshift does not automatically reclaim and reuse space that is freed when you delete rows and update rows.

Before running VACUUM, is there a way to know or evaluate how much space will be free from disk by the VACUUM?

Thx

References:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html

Comment: If you are trying to evaluate the need for VACUUM, don't forget that VACUUM also actually sorts your data based on your SORT KEYS. It is also not recommended to get too close to your disk storage limit as you need it for temporary tables that are created by your queries. Try to stay below 70% for best performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the amount of storage that will be freed up from a vacuum command by looking up the tbl_rows column in the [svv_table_info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html) view.  This includes rows that are marked for deletion.  Compare that to a select count(*) from the same table and you'll have a ratio.  Something like this on a theoretical table named factsales.

```
select    (select cast(count(*) as numeric(12,0)) from factsales) /
    cast(tbl_rows as numeric(12,0))
    as "percentage of non deleted rows" 
    from svv_table_info where "table" = 'factsales'
```

There doesn't appear to be a straightforward way to execute dynamic SQL and cursors so to get this same ratio across all tables you'd have to execute the code from an external source or programming language i.e. python.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an extremely accurate way, but you can query svv_table_info and look for the column deleted_pct. This will give you a rough idea, in percentage terms, about what fraction of the table needs to be rebuilt using vacuum.

You can run it for all the tables in your system to get this estimate for the whole system.

Comment: There is no such column. The closest is pct_used but it just tells you how much space is used out of the capacity of the entire table which tells nothing about the space that is ready to be removed. Anyway the table is interesting, upvoting :-)

Comment: You get half the story from that table, the tbl_rows col includes all rows, including those marked for deletion.  I posted an answer with more details.